# margin or positioning some paragraphs in the bottom right of an rotated A4 with itext

Tags: java, itext

i have some trabbel when tring to positioning document contenant to the right bottom of an rotated A4 
there is some of my code

```
        pageSize = new Rectangle( 842f,595f);
        document1 = null;
        document1 = new Document(pageSize, 0, 
                    0,pageSize.getWidth(),
                pageSize.getHeight()-263);

        file = new FileOutputStream(".//temp//page1.pdf");

        pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document1, file);

        //document1.setPageSize(pageSize);
        //document1.setMargins(0,   
                    document1.leftMargin()-332.20f, 595.28f,0);
        semaphore++;
        while (semaphore < 1)
            ;
        document1.open();
       ...

       MultiColumnText mct1 = new MultiColumnText(document1.top(),
                    document1.bottom());
       ...
            document1.add(mct1);
```

i get closer to my need by this code,i'v tried setsize,setmargins ...
i'v used pageSize=new Rectangle(PageSize.A4.rotate()) but same thing,or got blanck page

Comment: You use the constructor *Document(Rectangle pageSize, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom)* with extremely suspicious values. That been said, you probably should make your task clearer, e.g. by means of a sketch out sample document.

Comment: because i must print with some specific printer adapted to A4,on a specific form paper,the position of the MultiColumnText must be left bottom

Comment: `MultiColumnText` was removed from iText a mighty long time ago. This is probably a question about an obsolete, no longer supported, no longer to be used version of iText. Let's all ignore it.

Comment: so i should recode ,ok thanks